# How to do a RewriteRule that gets fired from any directory and redirects to root when a specific file is requested?

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to do a rewriterule so that whenever a client calls log-out.php it gets redirected to the root where the file exists. 
Current solution:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/log-out.php$ domain.com/log-out [L]
```

I am not good at rewrites and can't find anything on the topic where a rewriterule redirects to the root where the requested page exists. I want to do this whenever the log-out file is called nomatter the directory. My current solution creates an internal server error which of course isn't useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should exclude a target from your rule like this :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/log-out(\.php)?$
```

What happened is that you catch every request that end with `log-out.php` then redirect it to `domain/log-out.php` including the traget as well and that why there is looping .

Make the rules like that :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/log-out(\.php)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/log-out(\.php)?$  /log-out [L]
```